# Accessing data within multidimensial array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, multidimensional-array

This is what a var_dump looks like (below). I'm trying to access the "meta_key" and "meta_value" from each of the items in the array.

Assuming the name of the array is $the_array, I've tried things like:

```
$metakey = $the_array[0]["meta_key"];
```

and

```
$metakey = $the_array[0][2];
```

But nothing seems to be returned when I try those. In fact, there must be an error, because everything stops at that point. What am I doing wrong?

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#224 (4) {
    ["meta_id"]=>
    string(3) "184"
    ["post_id"]=>
    string(2) "56"
    ["meta_key"]=>
    string(17) "wpsr_product_link"
    ["meta_value"]=>
    string(63) "http://www.greenandblacks.com/ca/what-we-make/bars/dark-85.html"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#234 (4) {
    ["meta_id"]=>
    string(3) "182"
    ["post_id"]=>
    string(2) "56"
    ["meta_key"]=>
    string(17) "wpsr_product_name"
    ["meta_value"]=>
    string(34) "Green & Black's 85% Dark Chocolate"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#223 (4) {
    ["meta_id"]=>
    string(3) "183"
    ["post_id"]=>
    string(2) "56"
    ["meta_key"]=>
    string(18) "wpsr_product_price"
    ["meta_value"]=>
    string(5) "$3.49"
  }
  [3]=>
  object(stdClass)#236 (4) {
    ["meta_id"]=>
    string(3) "186"
    ["post_id"]=>
    string(2) "56"
    ["meta_key"]=>
    string(19) "wpsr_product_rating"
    ["meta_value"]=>
    string(3) "4.5"
  }
  [4]=>
  object(stdClass)#222 (4) {
    ["meta_id"]=>
    string(3) "185"
    ["post_id"]=>
    string(2) "56"
    ["meta_key"]=>
    string(20) "wpsr_product_summary"
    ["meta_value"]=>
    string(114) "Sed lobortis adipiscing turpis, tempus rutrum enim faucibus eget. Donec convallis arcu non massa convallis mollis."
  }
}
```

Comment: Whenever something doesn't work, enable `error_reporting`. PHP provides help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have objects inside your array so you access your property like that:

```
$metakey = $the_array[0]->meta_key;
```

Comment: @JasonMayoff - If it worked, it would be good to accept his answer.

Comment: I tried to accept, but was told I had to wait 10 min. This was my first opportunity since then, to come back and click the check mark.